# CSS Hover on stacked elements

Tags: css, hover

I currently have multiple stacked elements - Image + Text + Icon and want only the icon to animate when any elements are hovered over.

```
<style>
  .hvr-forward {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.hvr-forward:hover, .hvr-forward:focus, .hvr-forward:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
  transform: translateX(15px);
}
</style>

<div class="container hvr-forward">
   <div class="1"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
   <div><p class="2">Some Text <i class="3"></i></p></div>
</div>
```

If I apply the hover effect to the container div, as expected, all elements have the effect.

If I apply the hover effect to just the icon, I still need the effect to occur if the image or text are hovered over.

Is it possible to disable the animation through css on classes 1, 2 to keep the hover area but only have 3 use the effect?

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do that when you hover over the container, the style for the image should work.

```
.hvr-forward:hover .1, .hvr-forward:focus .1, .hvr-forward:active .1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
  transform: translateX(15px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, made me realise I was looking at this one the wrong way. Appreciate the help :)